# Como esconder mensagem de erro vindo de uma API usando Ajax, Fetch ou Axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express.js, fetch

Boa noite pessoal, sou iniciante com JavaScript, e estou desenvolvendo as funcionalidades de um CRUD, quero usar os verbos HTTP corretos para cada função (obs: Sei que usar os verbos HTTP é somente convenção) enfim, minha aplicação para teste tem o seguinte ambiente:

- JavaScript Vanilla
- Nodejs
- Express
- MongoDB

A parte do Backend está feita, e está funcionando normalmente, irei por uma rota para exemplificar:

```js
router.post('/add', async (req, res) => {
  if (await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }))
    return res.status(400).send('Error user already exists.');

  await User.create(req.body, (err, user) => {
    if (err)
      return res.status(400).send({ error: 'Failed to insert documents.' });

    return res.json(user);
  });
});
```

Como o código acima informa, é uma rota para adicionar o usuário, primeiro verifico se o usuário existe no banco, como parâmetro uso o campo de **email** pois no meu Model ele é um item único, se ele existir vai retornar um erro se não, irá adicionar o usuário.

Como já informado, tentei de várias maneiras tirar a seguinte mensagem de erro:

[image: Error]

```js
fetch('/test/add', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    name: 'test',
    age: '20',
    email: 'test@gmail.com',
    gender: 'male',
    developer: 'yes',
  }),
})
  .then(res => {
    if (res.ok) {
      return res.json();
    } else {
      return Promise.reject({ status: res.status, statusText: res.statusText });
    }
  })
    .then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(err => console.log('Error, with message:', err.statusText));
```

Eu forcei um erro, adicionando os mesmo dados que já foi inserido e como já dito o campo **email** é único, então internamente o MongoDB iria estourar um erro, eu trato ele no Backend, mas no Frontend não tenho controle.

Gostaria muito de usar **Async/Await** e poder controlar as mensagens de erros, e também queria que a resposta em que meu Backend retorna fosse vista no Frontend também, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: É complicado prever todas e quaisquer erros. Vale lembrar que na criação de um usuário pode ser previsto se o usuário já existe e enviar essa mensagem de erro, mas existem erros que é bom ser tratado no Front-end, eliminar todos os erros não acho válido e também que o excesso de erros também não é bom precisa de um meio termo

Comment: Os verbos Http denota um padrão e que deve ser seguido, não acho que seja somente convenção

Comment: @Virgilio Novic, sim quero tratar os erros nos Frontend o último código faz isso mas, mas simplesmente é como se a tratativa dos erros simplesmente não existissem, são ignorados, estoura X erro para mim, eu queria mostrar uma mensagem mais amigável para o usuário mas não estou conseguindo, você sabe algum meio para eu contornar isso?